# User preferences: "Preferred tab" feature

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

I have noticed that there are very few options in our user preferences across SE's sites. Although I've seen people requesting to remove the "preferences" tab, I think maybe it would be a good idea to improve it instead.

I have a little suggestion, I'll throw it out here and I would like to know your thoughts on that.

### My suggestion

Add a "**Preferred Tab**" option to user's preferences.

### The concept

Every time you visit a user's profile (or even your own), you land at the "Summary" tab. That's quite fair, as the name says it's a general summary about the user.

Nevertheless, some people may care more specifically about the user's (again: or even your own) **questions**, **answers**, **activity** or any other information on those tabs (tags, badges, favorites, bounties or reputation). Therefore, It would be nice to land straight at your desired preferred tab whenever you visit a user profile.

### Why to implement it?

**It's one click *less***, as simple as that. "Ooooh, but you're just being lazy!!" - nope.

First, loading one page instead of two to get where you want reduces page requests / server load. Probably user's profiles requests aren't that significant in terms of server load - but hey, it's something.

Second, it helps much more when accessing the page from mobile. You save yourself some time and even a little carrier's data consumption.

---

I'm quite aware that this suggestion is nothing hugely awesome, it's just a simple idea I had. It ain't gonna change the world, but - at least for me - it's something.

Let me know what are your thoughts on that!